# Stay in the same Wizard Step after clicking Next Step

Tags: javascript, sapui5, wizard

Trying to create a Wizard using SAPUI5, I can't find how I can prevent the wizard from going to next step when I click Step 2 for example. I need to check something but I don't want to hide the Step 2 Button, I want to have verification after clicking on it.

My Wizard Step :

```
<WizardStep id="step1" validated="true" title="Step1" complete="goToTwo"></WizardStep>
```

I've tried having this in goToTwo function for complete method to prevent the wizard from going to next step but it doesnt work :

```
goToTwo: function (oEvent) {
        var cntrlStep1 = this.getView().byId("step1");
        this.getView().byId("wizard").goToStep(cntrlStep1);
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to change the `validated` property of your wizardstep.
I assume you want to start with an non-validated state to make sure the user cannot go to step 2 unless the verification is done:

In  that case you could start from a `validated = false`:

```
<WizardStep id="step1" validated="false" title="Step1" complete="goToTwo"></WizardStep>
```

Or if you want to set the validated property in JS:

**In JS**

```
var step1 = this.getView().byId('step1');
step1.setValidated(false);
```

Once your verification is done, you can set the validated state to true and you can continue to step 2

```
var step1 = this.getView().byId('step1');
step1.setValidated(true);
```

Comment: this would be the solution if I wanted to hide the next step button and show it only when the verification is done. but what I want to do is have the next step showing always and then verify when I click on it.

Comment: hmm how about writing your  own custom wizardstep?

Answer (score 0):

```
goToTwo: function(oEvent){
  var step = this.byId("step1");
  var wizard = this.byId("wizard");
  if (you need to put your validation here){
     wizard .discardProgress(step);
     oEvent.destroy();

  }
}
```

Comment: instead of  oEvent.destroy(); you can write step.fireComplete();